# How to write a Python script to remove all files ending with .log in 10 different directories

Tags: python

Please provide a Python script which can delete all `.log` files in 10 different directories which are older than 5 days.

Path1 is like `abc/bcd/def/xyz/fkd/.log`
Path2 is like `abc/bcd/def/mnq/kjf/.log`

and so on, the first three directories are same but it differs after that.

Below is the script which I have prepared which gives me complete list of log files in all directories.

```
import time from time import strftime, gmtime

NOW = time.time() 
LOG = open('/home/vvivek/cleanup.log', 'a')

for PATH, DIR, FILES in os.walk('/tibco/bw/app/'): 
    for FILE in FILES: 
        if os.path.splitext(FILE)[-1] == '.log': 
            FILE_ = os.path.join(PATH, FILE) 
            CREATE_TIME = os.path.getmtime(FILE_) 

            if (NOW - CREATE_TIME) // (24 * 3600) >= 7:
                LOG.write(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
                LOG.write('|FILE DELETED|') LOG.write(FILE_) 
                LOG.write('\n') 
LOG.close()
```

I have not included `os.remove()` as currently I still need to make changes in the code and also it is not filtering files which ends with `.log.Somenumber`.

Note: Also, I am new to Python so I would love some coordination here rather then asking for complete code.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: "Please provide a python script" - That's not how SO works. We are not coding service we are Q&A forum. You need to write the code yourself and if you have problems you can't solve you ask about them and we try to help. 

With that said, iterating files and deleting with patterns in Python is quite easy, if you want I wrote a helper lib for that sort of things http://pythonhosted.org/fileter/. But you don't really need the lib, its really quite simple Python code you can start here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/267/files-folders-i-o#t=201611070801099604329

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta    
import glob

five_days_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=5)

for file_name in glob.glob(r"/folder_root/**/*.csv", recursive=True):
    modified_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(file_name))

    if modified_time < five_days_ago:
        print(f'Last modified: {modified_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}   {file_name}, ')
        #os.remove(file_name)     # uncomment when you are sure it has found the correct files
```

It uses Python `glob.glob()` to recursively give you all the `.csv` files under a given root folder.

If the modified date is more than five days ago, `os.remove()` can be called to delete the file.

Comment: Hi Martin ,Thanks for the suggestion. I have wrote below code which is fulfilling my need to traverse through the directories and list log files older then 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
import os

os.system("rm *.log")
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the script which I have prepared which gives me complete list of log files in all directories.

```
import time
from time import strftime, gmtime

NOW = time.time()
LOG = open('/home/vvivek/cleanup.log', 'a')

for PATH, DIR, FILES in os.walk('/tibco/bw/app/'):
        for FILE in FILES:
                if os.path.splitext(FILE)[-1] == '.log':
                        FILE_ = os.path.join(PATH, FILE)
                        CREATE_TIME = os.path.getmtime(FILE_)
                        if (NOW - CREATE_TIME) // (24 * 3600) >= 7:
                                LOG.write(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
                                LOG.write('|FILE DELETED|')
                                LOG.write(FILE_)
                                LOG.write('\n')
LOG.close()
```

I have not included `os.remove()` as currently I still need to make change in the code and also it is not filtering files which ends with .log.Somenumber.

Note: Also,I am new to Python so I would love some coordination here rather then asking for complete code

Thanks,